# Exclude year/month from url regex

Tags: regex

I have such working regex

```
([0-9]{1,})/([^\/.]+)/?$
```

How can I exclude such urls from matches:

2000/01/

2014/09/

but still catch such urls:

2000/13/

5000/09/

Comment: While `2000/13/` is not valid, `5000/09/` surely is. It will happen a couple of millenia later. You need to get more specific with this regex.

Comment: ok, more specific condition: years from 1990 to 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you define what a Year/Month precisely means? Anything with `19??|20??/1-12`?

In that case the regex can use a Negative Look ahead to exclude these

```
/(?!(?:199[0-9]|20[012][0-9])/(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/)([0-9]{1,})/([^/.]+)/$
```

It's a very crude system, but it would remove anything that comes close to what you'd probably call a date to be excluded.

You can [experiment with the expression here on regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=ae2c6b18-43fa-421c-8256-9984aec620a7).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is quite close to what I need. But I can not understand why this expression does not pass such strings: /2000/112/ or /2000/1s/

Comment: I think I found working solution, there must be additional slash at the end of 2nd non-capturing group /(?!(?:199[0-9]|20[012][0-9])/(?:0[1-9]|1[012])/)([0-9]{1,})/([^/.]+)/$